# Unable to run app on simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-extensions

When I try to run the project in simulator, I get the error:

> Failed to create plugin placeholder for
>   /Users/zc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPhoneHandheldACT-cwlfykavlwlqwlhbecjubziblyzi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPhoneHandheldACT.app/PlugIns/CallerID.appex

The build is successful, but run gives me the error.

This happened after I started re-organising the files in my project.

I tried deleting the derived data, clean and restarting the Xcode but it didn't help.

Comment: Try Product -> Clean

Comment: Tried it but it is still the same. @MartinMuldoon

Comment: "This happened after I started re-organising the files in my project" Well obviously you made some bad change when you did that. Undo it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the CallerID.apex from the embed framework section in Build Settings fixed this error.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that the version and bundle version of my widget configuration intent target didn't match the versions of the widget and the app.